# Extract fields from date

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a date field in `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format as a string and I want to extract in new fields the value of day of the week in Scala. For example, I have the dataframe `df`:

```
df.show()

------------
date
-----------
12/14/2017
12/13/2017
```

I want to do get the following output:

```
--------------------------------------------
date      | day  | month | year | DayOfWeek
--------------------------------------------
12/14/2017| 14   | 12    | 2017 | Thursday
12/13/2017| 13   | 12    | 2017 | Wednesday
```

I currently have this code:

```
df.withColumn("day", dayofmonth(to_date(df("date"),"MM/dd/yyyy")))
  .withColumn("month", month(to_date(df("date"),"MM/dd/yyyy")))
  .withColumn("year", year(to_date(df("date"),"MM/dd/yyyy")))
  .withColumn("dayofweek", something(to_date...)
```

I didn't found the function to extract dayofweek - how should I do it?

Another question, is using the functions `dayofmonth`, `month`, `year` the best option for performance or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_format` and specify the format as `"EEEE"` to get day of week. This will give you the full name, simply use `"E"` if you want it shortened, i.e. Mon instead of Monday.

```
df.withColumn("dayofweek", date_format(to_date($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy"), "EEEE"))
```

From a performance perspective, I do not believe you need to worry. The functions you are using, including the one above, are all fast and not very complex. Using another perspective, if another way would be faster, then these functions would most probably use that way.